# How to know the value of the iteration in a for-each in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, foreach, collections

I need to print some data on screen stored in a `String` array that looks this way:

```
String[] names = {"Joe", "Jessica", "Javi", "James", "Kevin"};
```

I was trying to execute it this way, using a for-each clause:

```
for (String i: names) {
   System.out.print(name);
   System.out.println(",");
}
```

The output of this would be:

```
Joe,
Jessica,
Javi,
James,
Kevin,
```

But I want to get rid of the last comma. In a normal each clause, I would just create an if clause that can control this:

```
for (int i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(name);

    if(i!=names.length - 1) {
         System.out.println(",");
    }
}
```

Can I do the same thing but in a for-each clause? How can I control if the iteration it's in the last data section?

Comment: You can build a `String` or `StringBuilder` instead of printing immediately, then remove the last comma with something like `substring` and print out the `String` together.  If you really want to keep the enhanced `for` loop.

Comment: @Andornicus You added the `java-8` and `java-stream` tags, but how do you know the Java version?  The question is about enhanced `for` loops which have existed since Java 5.

Comment: @Nexevis hm, you're right. I'm so used to java-8's streams, that "foreach" reminds me of foreach method on streams and collections, thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be addressing your question on where you can know the "value" of the iteration when using an enhanced `for` loop.

The equivalent implementation of a `for-each` or enhanced `for` loop for collections is not exactly your loop of `for (int i=0; i<names.length; i++)`, if `names` is a `List`.

The equivalent loop written out for `for (String i: names)` would look something like this:

```
String[] arr = {"Joe", "Jessica", "Javi", "James", "Kevin"};
List<String> names = Arrays.asList(arr);
for (Iterator<String> i = names.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    String str = i.next();
    System.out.print(str);
    System.out.println(",");
}
```

Where enhanced `for` loops are built upon an `Iterator` for `Collections`, as seen [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) in the Java 5 documentation from when enhanced `for` loops were initially created.

However, in your example you are using an array.

For arrays the earlier documentation states:

> The for-each construct is also applicable to arrays, where it **hides the index variable** rather than the iterator. The following method returns the sum of the values in an int array:

As you can see, you *cannot* access the index variable when using an enhanced `for` loop, and if you are required to access it for the array, you should resort to a standard loop instead.

For your current example, there are solutions such as `String.join` mentioned by other answers if you also do not want to use a standard `for` loop, but I believe those have been explained well enough already.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
var a = String.join(",\n", List.of("a", "b", "c"))
```

As @RealSkeptik suggests it can be simplified as:

```
var a = String.join(",\n", "a", "b", "c")
```

I find it a bit more readable in this case than transforming the `String`s as a stream.

Then

```
System.out.println(a)
```

results in:

```
a,
b,
c
```

Comment: You don't actually need the `List.of` part.

Comment: @RealSkeptic you're right, thanks! I didn't even notice the varargs

Answer (score 1):

You can use `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(names,",\n");`

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] names = {"Joe", "Jessica", "Javi", "James", "Kevin"};
String a = String.join(",\n",names);
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: pretty much Andronicus' answer, just 12 minutes later.

Comment: My bad, should've refreshed the page before posting. And yes, this took me more than 12 mins to think and type :)